# How to generate a liquibase rollback script using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, rollback

I have a simple changeset for creating a table and the rollback is drop'ing the same. I want a rollback script to be generated each time springboot is started. Any help?. many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`liquibase.rollback-file` is the field which can be used to generate a roll-back script by spring-boot. Which we need to run manually to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you this in place:

```xml
<changeSet id="new_table_change" author="the_man">
   <createTable tableName="new_table">
       <column name="id" type="int"/>
   </createTable>
   <rollback>
       <dropTable tableName="new_table"/>
   </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

With this in place, you can always, as part of your pipeline, you can generate the rollback script with the following command:

```sh
mvn liquibase:futureRollbackSQL
```

For your current problem, if your environment allows, you can do the following:

- Shutdown your application
- Rollback using one of the command options: rollback to a Date (`mvn liquibase:rollbackToDateSQL <date_time>`) or number of steps (`mvn liquibase:rollbackCountSQL <no_of_steps>`)
- Run the `mvn liquibase:futureRollbackSQL` and save the results
- Apply your changes again by starting your application again

Comment: Theres' a spring boot option where we can specify location for Rollback script(which is auto generated during application starts) in properties file.

Comment: I forgot the field name, I was hoping someone can help me on that, but thanks.

Comment: @FrancisRaj I looked around, haven't tried this but check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49635531/4878465